# Image slide show in Android

Tags: android

I am making an application in android for picture slide show. I have tried the following code:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {      
    @Override     
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        Drawable backgrounds[] = new Drawable[2];   
        Resources res = getResources();        
        backgrounds[0] = res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on); 
        backgrounds[1] = res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off);         
        TransitionDrawable crossfader = new TransitionDrawable(backgrounds);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageDrawable(crossfader);   
        crossfader.startTransition(3000);      
    }   
}
```

This code successfully bring the new image on top but previous image is not faded out.
Can anyone help me on it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the cross fade on your transition to have both of your images fade. Use the method `setCrossFadeEnabled` to enable it by setting it tu `true`.

See documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html#setCrossFadeEnabled(boolean)